# TCP communication between console and MFC

Tags: tcp, mfc, console

I want to implement TCP communication between win32 console application and MFC application, I made console application as client and MFC application as server, but the server cannot accpet the connecting request from client. So I want to make sure that the TCP mechanism whether works between win32 console and MFC?

Comment: Sure, it should work -- please show some code

Comment: It can work, but it depends on how you are implementing the socket. The MFC socket wrapper classes depend on the MFC message loop, but a console app does not have a message loop.